# How to determine lengt of text from multiple li's in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to learn js and jquery. For a project I have an HTML list that I am generating with php, so the number of li's is dynamic.

Now I want to calculate the total width from all the text in the li's. From another stackoverflow post I learned that you can wrap a span around text and calculate the length in px with:

```
$("#id").width();
```

But because I have multiple id's I don't know how to do this. Is there maybe a simpler way to accomplish this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How much simpler can this be?  Besides, right now you don’t even have a non-simple way to do what you want.

Comment: I dont want to be rude, but this is no `tutorial on demand` service. Your problem is so basic and broad that you should probably try to figure out how [jquery selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) work, so you are able to select the right elements. Then go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

var width = $("#Ul").text().trim().length * 6;

Explanation for Jquery newbies like me:

.text() gets all text from ul 
.trim() removes spaces from the text
.length determines the number of characters

I multiply the number of characters by the average px with of a character, in my case 6

I hope this will help someone in the future